# Which categories do I need to measure of my DB Performance?

Tags: database

I have written a DB. It's nothing big, you'll probably never see it, but I want to know how good my DB is and compare it to the big. Which times (categories) do I need to measure (time of x inserts, updates, etc) and where can I find comparison values of other DBs. (haven't found any usable in my short google search).

Comment: As in you have written a database from scratch?  Do you mind sharing the source code?  I would be very interested.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com ??

Comment: @Sid I wrote a class in PHP that creates files and dirs. Its probably not what you expected. I'll share later, because I am not finished now

Comment: @huMptyduMpty thanks .. I havent thought about that. gosh we have a SE for databases